# How to encapsulate abstract class

Tags: c#, .net, oop, abstract-class, encapsulation

I'm working with OpenTelemetry and trying to encapsulate the logic by internal library which means prevent using OpenTelemetry public API and spread logic between the projects, means there is only one place to do the stuff. I close public usage by `<PackageReference Include="OpenTelemetry" Version="1.5.1" PrivateAssets="All" />` everything is fine with regular inheritances which mean I can inherit base logic and provide ability to manipulate it by internal even if it such as marker interface

```
public class OtlpOptions : OtlpExporterOptions {
}
```

I think would be great hide the OT api and prowide such as simple common access through the extensions like

```
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);            
 builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryTracing().WithOtelExporter().WithConsoleExporter();
 builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetryMetrics().WithConsoleExporter();
```

but the problem that is too many abstraction on it like https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Api/Trace/TracerProviderBuilder.cs
and I cannot create marker interface for abstraction class without reference on that abstraction which means encapsulation doesn't work and required particular reference. And I wanna know how to encapsulate the abstraction?

**UPD:**
It's kind a weird that if I call extension
`tpBuilder.WithOtelExporter()` it requires reference
other way if I call static method
`MyOpenTelemetryExtension.WithOtelExporter(tpBuilder)` it is not required reference

Comment: What do you mean by "it requires reference"? I don't have any experience with OpenTelemetry, but at the moment this question is really confusing...

Comment: @JonSkeet required a reference of the target abstraction library into consumer of the library which means webAPI<-MyExtensionLib<-OpenTelemetry required webAPI<-OpenTelemetry that i want to in fact encapsulate by MyExtensionLib

Comment: Okay, so you're talking about a package reference, rather than an object reference. That wasn't clear (and still isn't mentioned in the question - readers shouldn't have to read comments). I wouldn't expect it to matter whether you have an extension method or a plain static method - a [mcve] showing the difference (complete code, with the error message in the failing exmaple) would make it a lot clearer what you're asking.